On opening app first login screen is loaded and then moving to Home screen in expo react native
I React context API for persist login using JWT token for my APP.
When closing and opening the app at that time first login screen loading then home screen, How to fix the delay. Same thing happening when reloading the from the VS code.
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import { handleError } from "../utils/helperFunctions";
import { API_URL, AUTH_KEY } from "../constants/strings";
import { setAxiosAuthHeader } from "../utils/configHelpers";
import { AuthProps, ILoginDeatils } from "../interface/AuthInterface";

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthProps>({});

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [authState, setAuthState] = useState<ILoginDeatils>(InitialLoginState);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        const loadUserAuthState  = async () => {
            const loggedInDetails = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(AUTH_KEY);
            if (loggedInDetails) {
                const loggedInUserDetails:ILoginDeatils = JSON.parse(loggedInDetails);
                setAxiosAuthHeader(loggedInUserDetails.token);
                setAuthState(loggedInUserDetails);
            }
        };
        loadUserAuthState();
        setLoading(false);
    }, [])


    const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
        const loginInfo = { email, password };
        const result = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, loginInfo);
        if (!result.data.verified || !result.data.completedProfile) {
            return result;
        }
        const loggedInDetails: ILoginDeatils = {
            registerId: result.data.loginDetils.registerId,
            gender: result.data.loginDetils.gender,
            email: result.data.loginDetils.email,
            profileId: result.data.loginDetils.profileId,
            name: result.data.loginDetils.name,
            phone: result.data.loginDetils.phone,
            token: result.data.token,
            authenticated: true
        }
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync(AUTH_KEY, JSON.stringify(loggedInDetails));
        setAxiosAuthHeader(loggedInDetails.token);
        setAuthState(loggedInDetails)
        return result;
    }

    const logout = async () => {
        // Delete token from stroage
        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(AUTH_KEY);
        // Update HTTP Headers 
        setAxiosAuthHeader("")
        // Reset auth state
        setAuthState(InitialLoginState);
        Promise.resolve(true);
    }
    
    const value = {
        onRegister: register,
        onLogin: login,
        onLogout: logout,
        authState,
        loading,
        setAuthState
    };

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}

App.tsx

import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import FlashMessage from "react-native-flash-message";

import { fontsFamily } from './src/styles/fonts';
import { FormsProvider } from './src/context/FormsContext';
import { AuthProvider } from './src/context/AuthContext';
import { ThemeProvider } from './src/theme/ThemeProvider';
import AppNavigation from './src/navigations/AppNavigation';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts(fontsFamily);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fontsLoaded || fontError) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded, fontError]);

  if (!fontsLoaded && !fontError) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <FormsProvider>
          <AuthProvider>
            <AppNavigation />
          </AuthProvider>
        </FormsProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
      <FlashMessage />
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}

AppNavigation.tsx
import React from 'react'
import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';
import ExpoStatusBar from 'expo-status-bar/build/ExpoStatusBar';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import SideDrawer from './drawer/SideDrawer';
import Auth from './stack/Auth';
import { useAMTheme } from '../theme/ThemeProvider';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import AnimatedSplashScreen from '../components/uiElements/loader/AnimatedSplashScreen';

const AppNavigation = () => {
    const { authState, loading } = useAuth();
    const { isDark } = useAMTheme();
    
    if(loading){
        return <AnimatedSplashScreen/>
    }
    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ExpoStatusBar style={isDark ? "light" : "dark"} backgroundColor={'transparent'} />
            {
                authState?.authenticated ? (
                    <NavigationContainer>
                        <SideDrawer />
                    </NavigationContainer>
                ) : (
                    <NavigationContainer>
                        <Auth />
                    </NavigationContainer>
                )
            }
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    )
}

export default AppNavigation

Please some one help on this or share any github project for reference
Issue Video link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dnM6IIV5jCvzbrJuf1cV3ElVW7segKSZ/view?usp=drive_link

loadUserAuthState function runs asynchronously, so setLoading(false) will be executed before it is ready. One way to fix this is to move loading state handling within the function. Something like this:
useEffect(() => {
  const loadUserAuthState = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
...
    setLoading(false);
  };
  loadUserAuthState();
}, []);


Thanks for the reply, I tried what you mentioned above, Still I'm facing the issue.
